# using gl_texture_2d_array in openXR swapchain

Tags: opengl, textures, openxr

What is the purpose of ARRAY textures in openXR swapchains?

I wanted to make a single texture swapchain with two array slices, corresponding to each eye.
The runtime has created the texture as intended.
I have set the corresponding subImage.imageArrayIndex for each eye.
However it does not work (windows, openXR sdk 1.0.25, steamvr 1.24.6, valve index hmd), it would just show blank screen, as if I was not submitting any layers.

Using separate swapchain for each eye works as intended.

Bonus question: What is the purpose of swapchain textures with mipmaps?

Comment: "*corresponding to each eye.*" That *is* the purpose. How are you rendering to these images?

Comment: I used glFramebufferTextureLayer and just glClear. I have confirmed that the rendering was correct using nvidia nsight.